# How to Set AWS Region in JUNIT for external Jar (Unable to load region from system settings.)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, junit

I have downloaded an external Jar for using the common mechanism.This Jar and Project will run on AWS and hence require AWS Region internally. I have set aws_region value in c:/users//.aws/config for local running. The code implementation works fine after this. But the JUNIT test cases are still failing with below error:

```
12:16:56.439 [main] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.AwsRegionProviderChain - Unable to load region from software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.SystemSettingsRegionProvider@d1c5cf2:Unable to load region from system settings. Region must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_REGION) or  system property (aws.region)
```

This will work fine when i deploy code on server, but locally this is failing as it is not able to find the AWS region. Can anybody help me how to set/Mock AWS region in JUNIT?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is by adding a .config file to ~/.aws/ folder in "c:/users/" and setting the default region in that file.
example:
*[default]
region = us-east-1*